# How to check if first two characters in NSString are numeric?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, pattern-matching

I have some `NSString`s such as: "11Dosing", "10Dosing", "11Dosing".

I want to check if a particular string starts with two numeric characters.
How can I check this condition using an `if` statement?

Answer (score 2):

Using a regular expression: "^\d\d": "^" means begins with, "\d" means a digit (string syntax requires the "\" must be escaped with a "\").

```
NSString *string = @"11Dosing"; // Example string for testing, your string here.

NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"^\\d\\d" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"Starts with two integers");
}
```

To get a `BOOL` result:

```
BOOL startsWithTwoIntegers = range.location != NSNotFound;
```

Comment: i have three strings like that: "10Dosing","11Dosing","12Dosing" then how can i set the condition..

Comment: That works fine, the first lie is just for testing, it can be anything.

Comment: You substantially changed the question. It now does not make sense, you really need to provide more explanation of what you want.

Comment: By the way, +1 from me for using regex in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSString characterAtIndex: method to get the character, then you will be able to check if its a numeric value

Comment: but how using i statement. i have various number of strings

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSString's `(void)getCharacters:(unichar *)buffer range:(NSRange)aRange`.

```
if ([aString length] >= 2){
  unichar buffer[2];
  [aString getCharacters:buffer range:NSMakeRange(0,2)]
}
```

and then access them through buffer =>

```
if (buffer[0]>='0' && buffer[0]<='9') {//char1 is digit}
if (buffer[1]>='0' && buffer[1]<='9') {//char2 is digit}
```

Comment: but how can i check it using if statement?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

```
if ([[@"11Dosing" substringToIndex:2] integerValue] != 0) {
}
```

or (will work with @"00fsdfs")

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; 
if ([numberFormatter numberFromString:[@"11Dosing" substringToIndex:2]]) {
}
```

*Please note: If strings that begin with "00" are relevant in your case, use second code snippet.

Comment: Because it's good enough in most of the cases. Sometimes "0" just not relevant scenario.

Comment: This is not the point. Of course I will not use code which is not correct in 1% of the situations, but I will use it if this 1% failure is irrelevant to my purpose.

Comment: As you can see from his question, we are talking about somebody unexperienced with objective c. So I just wanted to give him simplest solution to his question. When you pointed out that my solution can fail in edge scenario I added another simple solution. But i think that first is still good enough to learn from and use.

Comment: I find it interesting that you are arguing for incorrect code.

Comment: I think you got my point after all. Added some remark to original answer.

Comment: *Please note: If correct code is relevant in your case use the `NSNumberFormatter` code snippet.

Comment: @IlyaK. The `integerValue` approach will declare success with `@"1xxxxx"`, which would seem to violate the OP's "two character" criteria. Also, as you point out, this approach doesn't handle zeros. The `NSNumberFormatter` approach will report success if one of the two characters was a space, decimal place or minus sign, whereas most of us assumed that that the OP meant that the first two characters were, themselves, numeric (though the OP wasn't clear). You also should test to make sure there were at least two characters in the string, or else `substringToIndex` can crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `NSPredicate` with regular expressions using `MATCHES`, e.g.:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '\\\\d{2}.*'"];

BOOL found = [predicate evaluateWithObject:string];
```

The `\d` says "match digit" (to represent `\d` in a `NSString`, you'd generally use `\\d`, but because you're then using this in a string within a string, you have to escape again, resulting in `\\\\d`). The `{2}` says we're looking for two of them. The `.*` says that the string can end with zero or more occurrences of any character (i.e. we don't care what follows the two digits). The net effect of this is "any string that starts with two digits."

While this is a compact way to employ regex, its power is best exhibited when you're dealing with  collections:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"11Dosing", @"1xDosing", @"10Dosing", @"11Dosing"];

NSArray *arrayOfObjectsWithTwoDigits = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]);
```

This will create a new array consisting of the first, third, and fourth items, as those are the ones that satisfy the predicate.